# Android drawing app intended for a single View needs to work in multi-view Bottom Navigation Activity app

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I'm a completely new Android dev and am rather lost at the moment. I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8zAQTa2rfE) as I try to enable drawing to a view in my app which is a `"Bottom Navigation Activity"` project that features three tabs--or fragments. See screenshot below:

[image]

The problem is that the tutorial is intended for an app with a single View and a single standard MainActivity. In this case, the following code is used in the `onCreate()`method in the project's `MainActivity.java` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState):
PaintView paintView = new PaintView(content: this):
setContentView(paintView);
  }
```

}

When I build a single view app, the code works great. No issues. But things can't work in my `"Bottom Navigation Activity"` project, because the fragments use a `ViewModel` type that doesn't offer the much needed methods of the `View` class. My app features 3 fragments, the first of which is named `HomeFragment`. It is on this fragment that I want all my drawing to take place. The default `onCreateView()` method for this fragment looks like so:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private HomeView Model homeViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflator inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(fragment: this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, attachToRoot: false);

return root;
 }
}
```

See screenshot below to see what I've tried to do. You will see that I've added a `View` class to my project called `PaintView` (just as created in the tutorial), which contains all the drawing code.

[image]

Unfortunately it generates the following compilation error:

```
Inferred type com.example.mobile_testapp_android_2_ui.home.PaintView for type parameter T is not within its bound; should extend androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
```

Any tips on how I can implement the tutorial's PaintView class so that I can use its methods to draw on the "HomeFragment" would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you and very cordially,

Wulf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is trying to create a `HomeViewModel` object with the `PaintView` class which is not possible. If you want to set `PaintView` as the view of your `HomeFragment`, you need to return an object of it as :

```
    //you can return any kind of view object as you like
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflator inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        PaintView homeFragmentView = new PaintView(requireContext());

        // PaintView class must extends View class
        return homeFragmentView;

    }
```

I hope, this helps.

---

[Learn more about Fragment here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating)

[Learn more about ViewModel here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: That worked! AWESOME! Thank you so much for unblocking me! I am much obliged!